# Creating button panel in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, panel

We plan to create some `Wechat` -like UI in our app, and we'd like to know how to create such a **button panel**.

*Please look at the screenshots below:*

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

**So the behaviour is:**

*screen shot 1* - is a `chat UI`, and there is a `bar` at the bottom containing a *text field*.

*screen shot 2* - clicking on the text field brings up the `virtual keyboard`.

*screen shot 3* - note there is a `+ button` in the *bar*, and clicking that button dismisses the virtual keyboard, revealing the **button panel** which contains extra buttons below the bar, and these buttons provides extra features like *uploading images, shooting photos*, etc.

How would I implement such a UI, more specifically, how would I implement the `button panel`? Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I hope you've tried something before asking. You can place the buttons below the view and scroll up the view when you need to reveal the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) for that purpose.
In brief Collection View contain N numbers of Item in N numbers of rows.

see this below example for more detail :

[part1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

[part2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22)

Comment: I think OP is asking how to reveal the `UICollectionView` after the keyboard is dismissed. Also, Please provide code examples instead of tutorial links.

Comment: @Raptor . "how would I implement the "button panel"?"  . I think he ask about     how to design this type of UI . still I will update my answer . and this tutorial is very good to understand UIcollectionView .some time link is better instead of writing whole code . what do you think?

Comment: why -1 . because answer is right and provide link?

Comment: I think mentioning a class and providing the links provides value on its own. Thanks, KDeogharkar.

Comment: my pleasure @lgc_ustc

Comment: Disagree. If you have chance to use WeChat (not recommend to use though, as Chinese government monitors your messages), you will see what OP is trying to ask i think. And link-only answers should be put in comments. (p.s. not me to -1)

Answer (score 0):

you can browse wechat ui layout. use **Reveal** [Revel official website](http://revealapp.com/)

if you want pop a window recommend last photo. you can use [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/)
 get last photo or video.

Comment: you know wechat ui layout. you can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create one template named "MediaBar" on `GitHub`, which is named "button panel" by you.You can see code here: [SeraZheng -- MediaBar](https://github.com/SeraZheng/MediaBar)

I customised "MediaBar" to input text by `'DTRichTextEditor'` and capture image by `CTAssertPickerController`, which you can find on GitHub. "MediaBar" is subclass of `"UIToolbar"`.

This is presentation of "MediaBar" within my demo.
[image: MediaBar]

And when you touch `textField` ,MediaBar will move to top of keyboard.

[image: MediaBar with keyboard]

I haven't contribute code for this repository so long. So you can fork this  to your repository and advance its feature.

Hope help you!